# How to skip the first char in a line - C

Tags: c

I have a simple program that reads a line, with 3 numbers. I need to skip the first number, which is the code from the "product".

So, I need to read just the second and third chars.

How can I do this?

The code until now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int calculate_price (number, value)
{
    int price=0;
    price= number*value;
    return price;
}

int main(void)
{
    int number, value, u,price;
    FILE  *bill, *total_price;
    bill= fopen("bill.txt","rt");
    total_price= fopen("total_price.txt","wt");

    if (bill== NULL)
    {
        printf("The file cannot be open.\nQuitting the program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (total_price== NULL)
    {
        printf("The file canno be written.\nQuitting the program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(bill, "%d %d",&number, &value) != EOF)
    {
        u=calculate_price(number, value);
        fprintf(total_price,"The total price is %d\n", u);
    }
    printf("File created sucessfully. Check the file.\n");

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you provide a sample input line, and indicate exactly which part you want to ignore?

Comment: Look at the substr() function.

Comment: if stng = "3 this is a test", see what substr(stng, 2) provides.

Comment: Just solved, i used an "unused" var.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(void)
{
    int number, value, u,price;
    int dummy; //this is a dummy var
```

...

```
while (fscanf(bill, "%d %d %d",&dummy, &number, &value) != EOF)
{
    u=calculate_price(number, value);
    fprintf(total_price,"The total price is %d\n", u);
}
printf("File created sucessfully. Check the file.\n");
```

**EDIT** previously I used a char for the dummy, as somehow I misunderstood the question for first, but I corrected it to be an int...

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is interesting, i had never tought on this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
fscanf(bill, "%*d %d %d", &number, &value)
```

From scanf documentation:

> An  optional  '*'  assignment-suppression character: scanf() reads input as directed by the conversion specification, but discards the input.  No corresponding pointer argument is required, and this specification is not included in the count of successful assignments returned by scanf().

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
fscanf(bill, "%d %d %d", &product, &number, &value)
```

... and then just ignore the value of `product`.

Comment: Thanks! I used &dummy, to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to `scanf` the number into a dummy (unused) variable:

```
int product, number, value;
...
while(fscanf(bill, "%d %d %d", &product, &number, &value)) {
    ...
}
```